# Is it ok to leave (use) null check errors in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-sharedpreference

```
Future<void> loadFavorite() async{
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState((){
      FavoriteButtons = (prefs.getStringList("favorite4") ?? <bool>[]).map((value) => value == 'true').toList();
    });
  }
```

As above, using shared to store the bool list locally.

However, if you create the code as above, the list will be empty with [] when you first connect. (Because you haven't saved anything in prefs.getStringList("favorite4") yet)

I am getting the error here because I have to utilize FavoriteButtons[1]. I found a way to solve this problem.
That's just using a null check error to make your code stop halfway through only the first run.
As a result of testing, there is no problem with using the app. However, I wonder if there will be any problems during deployment or actual use in the future.

```
E/flutter (13880): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
```

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you're doing when you say "Using a null check error".  Can you show the code you're asking about?

Comment: The problem is somewhere else. Not in the given part of the code. And yes, an unhandled exception is not good.

Comment: Added ! to prefs.getStringList("favorite4")!